# Can not run Azure function. Error - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider'). - Java, Spring Cloud Function, Azure function example

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, spring-cloud-function

I am trying to run Azure functions example, given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure). There is no change made in the sample application given and ran all the instructions (installing Azure CLI, Azure core tools 3) as exactly given in the documentation. But it gives following error.

```
[7/23/2020 1:05:52 PM] [INFO] {Application.main}: Azure Functions Java Worker  version [ 1.5.3]
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Application is shutting down...
[7/23/2020 1:06:52 PM] Starting worker process failed
[7/23/2020 1:06:52 PM] The operation has timed out.
[7/23/2020 1:06:52 PM] Failed to start language worker process for runtime: (null). workerId:9ee7574a-76a5-412c-9a11-dbf7bcaa3b9a
```

I have referred to all the questions on stackoverflow and github. Nothing seem to be working as a solution here. I have created an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/1107), and given all the information.

I have uninstalled and installed nodejs (required for core tools), core tools, and CLI multiple times, and tried to resolve this issue but I could not.

My question is what does it mean by "Provider" here. How to resolve this issue. Any pointer would be great.

Comment: This seems like a potential bug. Can you please raise an issue in spring Cloud Function - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues and link this post. Also if you can provide a reproducible test project (could be link to guthub repo) that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the response @OlegZhurakousky. I have created github issues. I will keep posting.

Comment: I tried to run a simple Java Azure function (without Spring cloud), and I received the same error. So I have created 2 separate github issues, one for core-tools and one for plugin, as follows. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2115 and https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/1107. I have not received any solution though. It is a blocker for me. If anybody knows what is to be done, it would be a great help if you put it here.

Comment: were u able to resolve it